Is every finite collection of points in $\mathbb{C}^n$ the solution to a compatible algebraic system?
Preliminaries:
Bezout's theorem tells us that if we have a system of $n$ multivariate polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$
$$P_1(x_1 .. x_n) = 0 \\ \vdots \\  P_n(x_1 ... x_n) =0 $$
Of degrees $d_1 ... d_n$ that has finitely many solutions, then the total number of solutions to this system counting multiplicity is equal to the product $d_1 d_2 ... d_n$
We also know from the fundamental theorem of Algebra that given any $m$ points $p_1 ... p_m$ with repeats in $\mathbb{C}$ the polynomial $(z-p_1)(z-p_2)...(z-p_m)$ is the unique polynomial with leading coefficient $1$ that has EXACTLY those points as zeroes.
Question:
We can ask a sort of converse question combining these two ideas.
Suppose I give you a multiset $M$ of $m$ points (with multiplicity) in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Now suppose that $m$ factors into a product of natural numbers $q_1 q_2 ... q_n$. Then does there exist a system of $n$ polynomials of degrees $q_1, q_2 ... q_n$ respectively whose solution set is exactly equal to $M$?
Bonus Street Credit if you can actually describe an algorithm to generate those polynomials given a set.
Why this might be hard to answer:
There doesn't exist a good notion of "factoring" a system of polynomials. Without the ability to systematically build up a system one factor at a time. We can't really use Bezout's theorem to accomplish what we desire for $n>1$ the way one can use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic in $n=1$.
Another approach might be something akin to Contradiction by Induction. We suppose its true for dimensions $1 ... n-1$. Then we consider $n$. Suppose there is a multiset $M_c$ of $m_c'$ points s.t. one of its factorizations into $n$ factors is not compatible. From here we need to somehow argue that there exists a set of points in $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ for which this is not possible. Again its not really clear how to proceed.
A better approach might be to attempt induction on both the dimension $n$ and the number points $m$. Suppose that for all dimensions $<n$ our representation property is true. AND for dimension $n$ there exists an $m>1$ s.t. for all $j < m$ it is true and for $j=m$ it is now false. This feels a bit more stringent but its not obvious to me how we can argue that we can generate an unpresentable system for some $j<m$.
A last ditch pair of ideas is perhaps adding the maximum degree of the polynomials $d$ to the induction step, and perhaps the induction step requiring $d,n,m$ be composite numbers so that we can exploit Bezout's multiplicative structure to make our counter examples. But this is all hot air now. I haven't been able to construct anything useful.

What if, for example, you take a set of 10 points in $\mathbb{C}^2$ that aren't all on a common conic?

So 10 factors into either $1 \times 10$ or $2 \times 5$. If the 10 points don't lie on a common conic then they cannot be the $2 \times 5$ system because they need to lie on the degree 2 curve. Yes! that probably kills this idea. And that explains why I was having a hard time proving it, because its just NOT true. Please post as an answer so I can accept :)

The terminology you’re looking for is “complete intersection”. Much ink has been spilled investigating the special features of finite sets of points (even in the plane) with the property you described, they’re quite interesting and important!

thank you for the proper terminology! I will now look into it :)

Consider a set of 6 points in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which do not all lie on a common conic -- for example, $\{ (0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,2) \}$.  Then $6 = 2 \cdot 3$, but clearly the set cannot be expressed as the intersection of a conic and a cubic curve if it's not even contained in any single conic.
